# Как согласовать слово «какой» в данном предложении?

Tags: согласование

Предложение: «Такие и не взглянут на жалких продавцов, каким (продавец – мужской род) считала себя девушка». Согласование во множественном числе ведь неверное?

Comment: Такие и не взглянут на жалкого продавца(то есть на неё, а не на "них"), кем(продавцом, а не жалкой, можно каким "жалким" продавцом, но у продавца не написано "жалкий" он или нет, пока не взглянешь - не узнаешь какой продавец, - кривова-то получится) считала себя девчушка.

Comment: "К которым относила себя" решает проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Девяткину многое из всего этого казалось нелепым и даже вредным для людей низкого звания, к каковым причислял он и самого себя. [Н. Д. Телешов. Начало конца (1933)]
Пример из нац. корпуса показывает, что  согласование (в подобных случаях) достигается причислением субъекта к группе однородных, с помощью конструкций «к каковым (к которым) причислял (относил)», «в каковые зачислял».
Применив подобную конструкцию получим: "Такие и не взглянут на жалких продавцов, к числу ( / кругу / лиге) которых относила себя девушка".